# What information to sign on Authentication Token

Tags: node.js, token, access-token, jwt

I'm using `jwt` with NodeJS for my authentication token. Currently, I sign the audience, the IP and the client on to the payload.

I also put the user's `guid` on the payload so that in subsequent requests, I can find the user using the `guid`; an example of a `guid` is `bd262477-8b93-4f2c-9dc9-175edf6e0d14`.

Is this bad or a security concern? I guess what I'm asking is what information should you put on the payload? Is `guid` okay or bad?

Can someone provide me a link that explains why (or why not) there is a security concern of what you include on the token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entire token should be signed, protecting all the claims in the token body.

Regarding what you can securely put in the token: it depends on where the tokens will be stored "at rest".  But generally speaking you should not put sensitive information in the token unless you are going to encrypt the token as well (encryption is a second step, in addition to signing)

I work at [Stormpath](https://stormpath.com) and we have several articles on the topic:

[Use JWT the Right Way!](https://stormpath.com/blog/where-to-store-your-jwts-cookies-vs-html5-web-storage/)

[Where to Store Your JWTs - Cookies vs HTML5 Web Storage](https://stormpath.com/blog/jwt-the-right-way/)

[Token Based Authentication for Single Page Apps (SPAs)](https://stormpath.com/blog/token-auth-spa/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the links, I'll give them a read. So if I were to put the user `guid` (not the `id`), is that a security concern? I'm doing this so that on subsequent requests, I can figure out which user is making a call. Alternatively, I can store the token in a DB along with any identifiable information that i may need. On every call, I read the token, find the query on the DB and go from there. Which approach is better?

Comment: Putting a user ID in the token is totally fine, so long as it's opaque (it doesn't actually tell you anything about the user) and it's sufficiently random (in other words, not an incrementing number per user).  Also: the JWT convention is to use the `sub` claim for this ID, aka the "subject" of the token

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the info. Yes, I'm using a guid for the "id", which is a random string!